# Calculating aggregated number of days in each month in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a table with  multiple columns and two of the columns are start_date and end_date.

I need to calculate the number of days in each month. Let's assume I have following data in my table

```
id | start_date | end_date    
1    04.01.2016   15.02.2016    
2    07.01.2016   22.01.2016    
3    16.05.2016   11.07.2016
```

I want an output as follows

```
Month |   numberOfTravelDays    
January     51    
February    15     
May         15
June        31    
July        11
```

This output I am expecting is the number of total travel days each month has been utilized. I am having trouble constructing the sql query for this. Can someone assist me on this?

This is what I have for now. And it's not doing the job. The below query also filters only this year's records(but ignore that).

```
select MONTH(start_date) as month,
    COUNT(DATEDIFF(start_date, end_date)) as numberOfTravelDays
from travel
where YEAR(start_date) = YEAR(CURDATE())
group by MONTH(start_date),
    MONTH(end_date)
```

Comment: Why are those fields not actual datetimes 'YYYY-MM-DD'?

Comment: yes they are actual date times although it isnt evident in my example data

Comment: There's an edit button

Answer (score 0):

Use a derived table:

```
select monstart,
       sum(datediff(least(m.monend, t.end_date) + interval 1 day,
                    greatest(m.monstart, t.start_date)
                   )
           ) as days_worked
from travel t join
     (select date('2016-01-01') as monstart, date('2016-01-31') as monend union all
      select date('2016-02-01') as monstart, date('2016-02-29') as monend union all
      . . .
     ) m
     on t.end_date >= m.monstart and t.start_date <= m.monend
group by monstart;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping out. I will try this and get back

Comment: you have hardcoded the monstart and monend. I have to pass the year to this query as a parameter. In that case this wouldnt work right

Comment: @DesirePRG . . . Just extend the derived table to include all years you care about (or better yet, but these in a real table) and use a `where` clause to select the years you want.